# Is this the best way to write this non-numerical/alphabetical sort?

Tags: javascript, regex, arrays, sorting

I have various styles of font objects grouped into arrays. Each font object has a property sub_family which is either Regular, Italic, Bold, Bold Italic (or some variation e.g. Italic is sometimes called Oblique). When they come out of the database they are in a random order and need to be sorted as above; Regular is always first, Italic second, etc.

Here's the sort function I'm using, it works but I wanted to see if you guys could come up with better/alternate solutions:

```
// input: ["Bold Italic", "Regular", "Bold", "Italic"]    
sortFont = function(a, b) {
    // regular
    if (/^([Rr]egular|[Nn]ormal)$/.test(a.sub_family)) { return -1; }
    if (/^([Rr]egular|[Nn]ormal)$/.test(b.sub_family)) { return 1; }
    // italic
    if (/^([Ii]talic|[Ii]nclined|[Ii]t|[Oo]blique|[Oo]bl)$/.test(a.sub_family)) { return -1; }
    if (/^([Ii]talic|[Ii]nclined|[Ii]t|[Oo]blique|[Oo]bl)$/.test(b.sub_family)) { return 1; }
    // bold
    if (/^([Bb]old|[Bb]d)$/.test(a.sub_family)) { return -1; }
    if (/^([Bb]old|[Bb]d)$/.test(b.sub_family)) { return 1; }
}
// output: ["Regular", "Italic", "Bold", "Bold Italic"]
```

thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a massively more efficient way of doing it that also lets you maintain it just by adding entries to a table:

```
sortKeys = {
    "regular": 1,
    "normal": 2,
    "italic": 10,
    "inclined": 11,
    "oblique": 12,
    "bold": 20,
    "bold italic": 30
};

function sortFont(a, b) {
    var aKey = sortKeys[a.sub_family.toLowerCase()] || 100;
    var bKey = sortKeys[b.sub_family.toLowerCase()] || 100;
    return(aKey - bKey);
}
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/MB76R/

Answer (score 2):

By using the i flag you can replace

```
/^([Rr]egular|[Nn]ormal)$/
```

with

```
/^(regular|normal)$/i
```

The i flag causes the regexp to ignore case on alphabetic characters. Note this will then allow names like REGULAR or ReGuLaR, use your original formulation if that would cause a problem.

Then replace

```
/^([Ii]talic|[Ii]nclined|[Ii]t|[Oo]blique|[Oo]bl)$/
```

with

```
/^(it(alic)?|inclined||obl(ique)?)$/i
```

The ? makes what precedes it optional.

Another option, if your font names are always consistent, is as follows :

```
var sorted = ["Regular", "Italic", "Bold", "Bold Italic"];
function sortFont (a, b) {
  return sorted.indexOf (a) - sorted.indexOf (b);
}
```

Here we find the index in a sorted array of names of each candiate font. Subtracting the two indexes provides the sort order.